# font irregular in google chrome web browser in windows 11 home OS

Tags: google-chrome

[image: text not proper in google chrome]

hi , i have cropped this from an incognito tab in google chrome . As you can see above that font of some letters is not proper . example - letter b,u,p,i have thin parts .

in chrome://settings/fonts?search=font i saw that standard and serif font is times new roman while sans-serif font is arial and fixed width font is consolas and mathematical font is cambria math . my chrome version is Version 113.0.5672.127 (Official Build) (64-bit) .

Please help me to figure out why is text rendering bad in browser ?

Hope I have shared relevant information , in case any other info is needed then please tell in comment.

Thanks.